# Prometheus ignores the settings storage.tsdb.retention.*

Tags: kubernetes, devops, prometheus

I have the following settings for deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: prometheus-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus
          args:
            - "--storage.tsdb.retention.time=2h"
            - "--storage.tsdb.retention.size=1KB"
            #- "--storage.tsdb.wal-compression"
            - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
            - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 500M
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 1Gi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: prometheus-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/prometheus/
            - name: prometheus-storage-volume
              mountPath: /prometheus/
      volumes:
        - name: prometheus-config-volume
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            name: prometheus-server-conf
  
        - name: prometheus-storage-volume
          emptyDir: {}
```

I limit the information to two settings:

1. --storage.tsdb.retention.time=2h - erases old information after 2 hours
2. --storage.tsdb.retention.size=1KB - limits the amount of stored information (it's for test. I tried other values: 1MB, 1GB etc.)

[the settings applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NArCm.png)

However, Prometheus ignores my settings and the data continues to be displayed in spite of the minimum size of 1KB.

The set minimum size ignored...

What is the cause and how to solve this problem?